# Sql summarize different rows

Tags: sql

I have a table named games:

```
id  player_a_id  player_b_id  player_a_result  player_b_result  turn 
 1     1           2             1                 0              1 
 2     3           4             1                 0              1 
 3     1           3             1                 0              2
```

I am trying to write a SQL query that will make a rating list of the table. Like this:

```
player_id  total score 
   1           2 
   2           0 
   3           1 
   4           0
```

I am not sure how to write the sql. Some help would be great!

Comment: Just curious -- is this homework?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! No messy `<br />` orgies necessary, either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(result)
FROM
(SELECT player_a_id AS player_id, player_a_result AS result FROM games
UNION
SELECT player_b_id, player_b_result FROM games) AS u
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY player_id
```

This is what I'm guessing you're after. This creates a subquery (the stuff in parens()) that combines (UNION) players a and b into one set, then groups by player and sums the results.

Comment: In the derived table, you need to make that `union` into `union all`.  Otherwise, the duplicate rows are eliminated, so player 1 only wins one game even though he won two.

Comment: That look advanced ^^ I tried to use the sql in Oracle but I got a error msg on: "AS u".

Comment: I removed the "AS u" and now it shows each players with their summarized gamescore. Wow, thanks.

Comment: @OlofAnonym  YW.  If that worked and resolved your question, then you should accept this answer.

Comment: Done. Hm I wonder if it´s possible to write the sql as an flat one, without using subquery.

Comment: Subqueries are often a 'code smell' that there might be a better way to design your db. The subquery is there so we can get a single set of all the players. If there were a players table and a games table this query would look very different and probably run much faster.

Comment: Yeah you probably right. I split the table games into two: game_info and players_playing_game. But now I find I have a lot more tables to connect to each others.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. how do you want to get ranking_score SUM? I mean what numbers/columns do you want to SUM? If you need to SUM values from the same column, e.g.:

table example:

```
`id`  `player_id`  `number`
 1     1            1
 2     2            15
 3     1            20
```

expected result:

```
`player_id`  sum(`number`)
 1           21
 2           15
```

You can simply use this:

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(`number`) FROM `table` GROUP BY player_id
```

SUM will count a result for all rows, GROUP BY is necessary to divide the total sum by player_id.
If you need to get a sum of different columns, it's necessary to prepare a procedure.

Comment: Yeah something like that, but I want to summerize both player a´s and b´s results. That seem to be the tricky part.